# Display The Map WIth some Address Entered by user using Google Places Api

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, google-places-api

I am Working on Google Maps Integration with My Application.

I have requirement Like , user can enter his/her Place(Address),City,State,Country.

Then I have to display the map for that address.

I tried with lat , lan i can not exact place marker.

Can anyone give me suggestions how to achieve this requirement.

Thank You All in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking at the geocoding service in the api docs - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder

Also see this working example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: Thanks for the answer achive that